# Distribute IRQs across multiple cores

Tags: centos7, interrupts, irq

I have a centos vm and I am trying to distribute the softirqs across multiple cores. I have modified the smp_affinity_list from 3 to 0-3 but instead of balancing the interrupts, it just moved the interrupts to cpu 0. is there a way at all to balance the interrupts?

I am using CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core). irqbalance service is already running on the machine.

Comment: have you tried to use irqbalance service?

Comment: its already running